# Different French keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, windows, internationalization

There are 2 Mac French keyboard layouts.

The standard one :
[image]

And another one :
[image]

I would like to use the second kind of keyboard on Windows. Meaning now if I plug it, the keys don't match, what gets sent to Windows is not what appears on the keyboard. With the first type of keyboard I could install a "French" "Mac" keyboard layout, that worked well. Thus I am looking for the relevant keyboard layout to install on Windows.

Where can I find it, and what is it called ?

The reason I am saying that the second keyboard is "standard", is because on a Mac, if one takes a US keyboard (with the key shapes like the second picture), and selects "French" as input language, then the mapping is exactly the same as the second picture.

Comment: What do you mean that you're looking to 'install on Windows'?  Do you mean a virtual keyboard or a real keyboard to use on a Windows PC?

Comment: @patrix  I don't think this is unclear, I have often seen similar questions.  It is common to find that the layout used by windows is not exactly the same as used by a Mac keyboard.  Windows provides special layouts for some of them, labeled (Apple).   For a non-standard layout as depicted here, you might have to roll your own.

Comment: @TomGewecke The second keyboard doesn't look like something from Apple at all. If the OP wants to use it with Windows in Bootcamp or within a VM running on macOS, it's borderline on-topic (but might find better answers in other places). If they want to use a non-Apple keyboard on a non-Apple computer (aka PC), it's off-topic (as you mention in your answer).

Comment: @patrix  I agree with the way you describe it, am just assuming it is the borderline on topic case.

Comment: @TomGewecke reopened, let's see where it leads to

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. I have added details to the question as to why this is "standard" and what I mean by "using on Windows". Basically Apple seems to have a builtin layout for this kind of keyboard

Comment: @Vic  Yes, all Apple keyboard layouts can be used on either the ISO or (one key less) ANSI (or even JIS Japanese) layouts.  The problem will lie with the software layouts used by Windows, which most of us here know little or nothing about.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to search online for a Windows keyboard called French (Apple).  See [this note](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250004917).  And it would be for your top picture.  Your bottom picture looks non-standard and non-Apple.  All European keyboards should be ISO and have the extra key next to the shift in the bottom row.

You might need to make a custom Windows keyboard with the MKLC app.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339

You should probably really ask in a forum for Windows instead of Mac.